# groovy binary edition vs groovy-all-jar

Tags: shell, groovy, jar, classpath

When I want to download groovy from here http://groovy-lang.org/download.html I get the "binary release". This means I have a directory structure with a `lib` and `bin` and an `embeddable` folder. In the `bin` folder there is a `groovy` shell script that let's me execute my own groovy sourcefiles. This `groovy` shell script uses the jarsin the `lib` directory. I however want it to use the jars in the groovy-all-jar in the `embeddable` directory. The reason is, that I dont want all the jars in the `jar` directory in my classpath as I need to use different versions.

How can I make the `groovy` shell script using the groovy-all-jar?

Comment: I don't believe there's a difference between using the separate jars or the groovy-all jar

Comment: As an extra piece of information, groovy-all will add 5MB more to your .jar file compared to using groovy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

groovy-all is usually for applications that want to support Groovy. So you just put it in your classpath.

If you want to use something like GroovyConsole from groovy-all using the shell scripts, you will have to edit the startGroovy. I suggest doing the following... remove everything in lib. Then find the line where STARTER_CLASSPATH is frist set and change it to use your groovy-all. I have not tested it, but that should work.

Since groovy-all contains only asm, commons-cli and antlr (in a jarjared version) anything that needs for example Jline (the shell console) will not work